# How can I use JavaScript returned values in Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Using Genexus, I am trying to set a Button's JSEvent property to do a simple value assignment:

```
Event Start
  DoAssignments.JSEvent("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + &Field1.InternalName + "').value = 'Hello!'")
endEvent
```

After this action (button_click), &Field1 seems to have the correct value.
But a simple Genexus assignemnt (&Field2 = &Field1) shows that, internally, for Genexus, this &Field1 is still empty.

[image]

How can I retrieve a JavaScript Value/functionReturn and use it in Genexus?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, it is always better to explore the GX javascript libraries to see if you can solve it by using them than trying to reverse engineer how it solves this issues. Your solution is good, but it is prone to broke if you ever change the version of GeneXus.

For example, what you wanted could be done with:

```
DoAssignments.JSEvent("onclick", "gx.fn.setControlValue('" + &Field1.InternalName + "', 'Hello!',false)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I also had to set the gxoldvalue attribute in order to assign values into Gx Controls via JavaScript .

```
Event Load

textblock1.Caption = '<script>' + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += ' function doAssignment() {'  + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += " var element = document.getElementById('" + &Field2.InternalName + "');" + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += " element.value = document.getElementById('" + &Field1.InternalName + "').value;" + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += " element.setAttribute('gxoldvalue', document.getElementById('" + &Field1.InternalName + "').value);" + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += ' }'  + chr(13) + chr(10)
textblock1.Caption += '</script>'  + chr(13) + chr(10)

DoAssignments.JSEvent("onclick", "doAssignment()")
```

Please let me know if there is any problem with this approach.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help you:

```
epftintins.JSEvent("OnChange","var a = document.getElementById('EPFTINTINS')[document.getElementById('EPFTINTINS').selectedIndex].text; console.log(a); if (a=='Juzgado' or a=='Fiscalía') document.getElementById('EPFTINNJUZ').disabled = false; else document.getElementById('EPFTINNJUZ').disabled = true; ")
```

I used that.